# Automatically changing SOME text size, not all

Tags: google-sheets

When I'm working in Google Sheets (taking notes for classes) -- If I bold some text it will automatically switch from font size 10 to 12. Then it becomes impossible to make smaller, even if I delete the text and retype it in there. How do I turn off this?